# Why FSCalendar sets different current page than manually set for week scope mode?

Tags: ios, swift, fscalendar

I use the following library to display calendar in my `UIView`:

https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar

This is how I define it in code:

```
let date = Date()
print("DATE: \(date)")
print("SCOPE: \(calendarView.scope.rawValue)")
calendarView.setCurrentPage(date, animated: false)
print("PAGEAFTERSET: \(calendarView.currentPage)")
print("SCOPEAFTERSET \(calendarView.scope.rawValue)")
```

and this is output on console after load:

```
DATE: 2023-05-29 08:18:59 +0000
SCOPE: 1
PAGEAFTERSET: 2023-05-31 22:00:00 +0000
SCOPEAFTERSET 1
```

And this is wrong, because when I get `calendarView.currentPage` then I receive JUNE 2023, instead of MAY 2023. Why?

[image]

When I swipe left on calendar to select PREVIOUS WEEK and then again right for CURRENT WEEK I have the following ouputs on console for `calendarView.currentPage`:

```
2023-05-21 22:00:00 +0000
MAY 2023
2023-05-28 22:00:00 +0000
MAY 2023
```

what is very correct.